# How do I get it to return every column in a table when using INNER JOIN on two tables,

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Table dbo.Ögon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqPva.png)

[Table dbo.CaseTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYZD7.png)

I have imported a .csv file and created a table out of the .csv file. 
It contains two columns that matches columns/values of a another table. 
This .csv file contains 2245 rows which also is the amount of rows in table I created called `dbo.Ögon`

Down below is the `INNER JOIN` query I've written.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ögon] O
ON P.Personnummer = O.Pnr;
```

This returns a result of 9085 rows which's not the result i was lookin for.

But!

If I write the query this way instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Personnummer, Fotodatum
FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ögon] O
ON P.Personnummer = O.Pnr;
```

I get the exact same rows as the .csv file or as in table `dbo.Ögon` but I also see two columns.

So. What i'm looking for as a result when running query, is to see every column instead of two columns with the amount of rows that I stated before.

To clarify.
Im looking for a column called CaseKey which does not exist in table `dbo.Ögon` but exists in table `dbo.CaseTable`

Hence why im looking for a query that returns all columns so I can see column CaseKey.

Hope I didn't make this too confusing :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (tsql <> mysql)

Comment: Please qualify ALL column names.  It is not clear where `Fotodatum` comes from.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Fotodatum exists in table dbo.Ögon and value looks like 2019-05-21 00:00:00.000. CreationDate is the column that exists in table dbo.CaseTable and matches Fotodatum in value

Comment: @GordonLinoff See my comment above

Comment: @jarlh i've posted sampte tables above,

Comment: You can make a group by returning min(id) as Id included in select * from ... inner join (mygroup by) on XX.id=Mygroup.id

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ive posted some sample tables above, hope its useful

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have duplicates -- I am guessing in the `ogon` table.  One method uses `ROW_NUMBER()`.  If this interpretation is correct, you can use:

```
SELECT p.*, o.*
FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] p JOIN
     (SELECT o.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.Pnr, o.FotoDatum ORDER BY NEWID()) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[Ögon] o
     ) o
     ON p.Personnummer = o.Pnr AND seqnum = 1;
```

Note that you would normally have an `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` to specify *which* row you want.

Comment: When I run you're script, i get this as a result                                                                         Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.